# ¿Funcíon para seleccionar y deseleccionar checkboxs en Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Muy buenas a todos. Tengo el siguiente inconveniente. Resulta que que cargo una tabla dinamicamente con ngFor, el la primera columna está el nombre de un producto, y en la segunda columna hay un checkbox por cada producto. Lo que quiero lograr seria que el checkbox que está en la cabecera de la tabla pueda activar y desactivar todos los demas checkbox, que como vuelvo a decir son generados dentro de un ngFor. Adjunto una imagen para que se entienda mejor.

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

```html
<table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
           <tr>
              <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
              <th scope="col">
                 <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" 
                    id="blankCheckbox" value="option1" aria-label="...">
                 </div>
              </th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let producto of productosEnProm">
               <td>{{producto.nombre}}</td>
               <td>
                  <div class="form-check">
                      <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" 
                      id="blankCheckbox" value="option1" aria-label="...">
                  </div>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

Muchas gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacerlo seria añadiendo una propiedad a tu array de objetos en este caso *productosEnProm* que por el momento solo tiene *nombre*, para el ejemplo llamare a esta nueva propiedad *checked* siendo del tipo booleano.

Entonces cada objeto tendría la forma: `{nombre: 'producto', checked: false}`, una vez tenga esta estructura crearemos un método para que cambie la propiedad checked de false a true y viceversa cada vez que ocurra el evento *change* en el checkbox superior, obviamente haciendo binding a la propiedad `checked` del input tipo checkbox que se encuentra en tu `*ngFor`.

El código final llegaría a ser de la siguiente forma:

**TypeScript**

```
productosEnProm = [
  {nombre: 'algo', checked: false},
  {nombre: 'algo2', checked: false},
  {nombre: 'algo3', checked: false}
];

checkOnClick(check: boolean) {
  this.productosEnProm.forEach(row => row.checked = check);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        <th scope="col">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input #check class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" (change)='checkOnClick(check.checked)'
                id="blankCheckbox" value="option1" aria-label="...">
            </div>
        </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let producto of productosEnProm">
            <td>{{producto.nombre}}</td>
            <td>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" 
                id="blankCheckbox" value="option1" aria-label="..." [checked]='producto.checked'>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: Entiendo entiendo. Pero no se si seria una solución fiable, ya que el array de productos lo consumo del backend.

Comment: Es una posible solución, hay otras formas que podrías intentar, por ejemplo simplemente podrías usar en el input `[checked]='check.checked'` en lugar de usar `[checked]='producto.checked'` para no tener que poner la propiedad *cheked* en tus objetos, pero bueno la cosa era al menos darte una idea. Saludos ;)

Comment: Si si entiendo. Al final decarté el tema de los checkbox. Pero muchas gracias por tu tiempo de responder. Saludos!